# How do I replace missing values in flat file with a NULL mark of appropriate data type?

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file with currency values. Some have values and some don't. So when I am importing data directly through SSIS, if there is no value in row, it is inserting **`0`** but technically there is no value. How can I replace these **`0`** value using derived column.

I tried the below expressions but both these expressions do not yield the expected results.

#### Expression 1:

```
MontlyAmt == "" ? NULL(DT_CY)
```

#### Expression 2:

```
MontlyAmt == "" ? NULL(DT_CY) : MonthlyAmt
```

How do I import the missing currency data from flat file into database using an SSIS expression?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an expression to retain **`NULL`** values. When you read the flat file using *`Flat File Source`* within the *`Data Flow Task`*, you need to check the box **`Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow`**. When you check this box, any column that has no value will be converted to *NULL* mark of that appropriate data type defined on the *Flat File Connection Manager*.

[image: Flat File Source Editor]